# one line "for" loop in an if test

Tags: python, if-statement, numpy

I want to run a series of commands on several elements of a `numpy.ndarray` that passed an `if` test.

The `if` test sets a filter for the lines in the `numpy.array` that contain the value `"nan"` (not `numpy.nan`) and a series of strings defined in a list.

My issue is with the second part of the if test here is basically how I coded it :

```
d=numpy.array(whatever data)
filter_list=["..", "..."]
for line in d:
     if (("nan" not in line) & ([filter_list[i] not in line for i in range(len(filter_list))]):
         "do commands"
```

So the "nan" part is working as expected but the other test is passed whether a ".." or a "..." is found in line or not.

I think the issue comes from the syntax what the second test actually returns is a combination [True/False, False/True] for which the boolean value is always `True`.

To sum up just focus on the second part of the test : I'd like a 1-line test that checks that none of the defined rejection strings is present in a list of values.

Comment: Ah, sorry Martijn, feel free to rollback my edit, I'll stop clobbering your fixes now

Comment: 'one line “for” loop' is called "list comprehension".

Answer (score 2):

`boolean_condition & ([<list_comprehension>])` is nonsensical. What will be the bitwise-and of a `bool` and a `list`?

Besides, the length of the `([ ... ])` part is always `len(filter_list)`, and therefore non empty, so as a boolean value this is always `True`.

You should

- Replace `&` (eagerly-evaluated bitwise and) with `and` (lazy evaluated, logical and)
- Replace

  ```
  [filter_list[i] not in line for i in range(len(filter_list))]
  ```

  with

  ```
  [exp for exp in filter_list if exp not in line]
  ```

And it should work.

A better solution, with lazy evaluation over the list:

```
filter_list = ["..", "...", "nan"]
for line in d:
     if not any(fi in line for fi in filter_list):
         "do commands"
```

Comment: "any()" is by far the superior solution as it omits the need to examine further values once it finds a true one. Also note that Elazar has carefully used a generator rather than a list comprehension. This avoids creating the whole list unnecessarily, and so will perform better over large data sets.

Comment: I think that from performance point of view, regex will be the fastest way. But it won't be as readable.

Comment: Thanks to you all that last one was exactly what I was looking for (I used "and" in the original code I just used & here for it was faster and not the source of the issue).

Comment: If you post a question about some obscure error, you better not change the syntax you've used. It might be confusing.